# I don't know where is the mistake and my console window won't close

Tags: c

I program this app but it doesn't work and my console window won't close 
I think my problem is in the "etoiler" fonction because he show me the first sentences "Bienvenue dans le Pendu !!"
this is my code it about a simple game that tell you to guess letter from a word:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void etoiler(int taille,char *mot_secret);
void verifiermot(char caractere,char *mot_secret,char *mot_secret_verif,int *nbre_coup);
char proposezUneLettre();
int main(){
     /* -------------variables-----------------*/

       char mot_secret_verif[]="MARRON";
       char mot_secret[strlen(mot_secret_verif)];
       char caractere;
       int nbre_coup=10;

     /*---------------traitement------------*/

       printf("Bienvenue dans le Pendu !!\n");
       etoiler(strlen(mot_secret_verif),mot_secret);
       while(nbre_coup>0 && (strpbrk(mot_secret,'*'))){
              verifiermot(caractere,mot_secret,mot_secret_verif,&nbre_coup);
              printf("Il vous reste %d coups a jouer\n",nbre_coup);
              printf("Quel est le mot secret? %s\n",mot_secret);
              printf("Proposez une lettre : ");
              caractere=proposezUneLettre();
              printf("%c",caractere);
       }

       if(nbre_coup<=0){
              printf("Perdu :p le mot secret etait %s",mot_secret_verif);
       }
       if(!strpbrk(mot_secret,'*')){
              printf("Gagne ! Le mot secret etait bien",mot_secret_verif);
       }
     return 0;
     }
/* ---------------------- les fonctions ------------------*/
void etoiler(int taille,char *mot_secret){
       int i ;
       for(i=0;i<taille;i++){
              mot_secret[i]='*';
       }
       }

void verifiermot(char caractere,char *mot_secret,char *mot_secret_verif,int *nbre_coup){
       int i ;
       int b=0;
       for(i=0;mot_secret_verif[i]!= '\0';i++){
       if(mot_secret_verif[i]==caractere){
              mot_secret[i]=mot_secret_verif[i];
              b++;
          }
        }
        if(!b){(*nbre_coup)--;}
       }
char proposezUneLettre(){
      char caractere = getchar();
      caractere = toupper(caractere);
       while(getchar()!='\n');
       return caractere;
}
```

Comment: You need `strchr`, not `strpbrk`.

Answer (score -1):

thank you Cool Guy for your answer
this is my new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
void etoiler(int taille,char *mot_secret);
void verifiermot(char caractere,char *mot_secret,char *mot_secret_verif,int *nbre_coup);
char proposezUneLettre();
int main(){
     /* -------------variables-----------------*/

       char mot_secret_verif[]="MARRON";
       char mot_secret[strlen(mot_secret_verif)];
       char caractere;
       int nbre_coup=10;

     /*---------------traitement------------*/

       printf("Bienvenue dans le Pendu !!\n");
       etoiler(strlen(mot_secret_verif),mot_secret);
       while((nbre_coup > 0) && (strchr(mot_secret,'*')!=NULL)){

              printf("Il vous reste %d coups a jouer\n",nbre_coup);
              printf("Quel est le mot secret? %s\n",mot_secret);
              printf("Proposez une lettre : ");
              caractere=proposezUneLettre();
              verifiermot(caractere,mot_secret,mot_secret_verif,&nbre_coup);
       }

       if(nbre_coup<=0){
              printf("Perdu :p le mot secret etait %s",mot_secret_verif);
       }
       if(!strchr(mot_secret,'*')){
              printf("Gagne ! Le mot secret etait bien %s",mot_secret_verif);
       }
     return 0;
     }
/* ---------------------- les fonctions ------------------*/
void etoiler(int taille,char *mot_secret){
       int i ;
       for(i=0;i<taille;i++){
              mot_secret[i]='*';
       }
       }

void verifiermot(char caractere,char *mot_secret,char *mot_secret_verif,int *nbre_coup){
       int i ;
       int b=0;
       for(i=0;i<strlen(mot_secret_verif);i++){
       if(mot_secret_verif[i]==caractere){
              mot_secret[i]=mot_secret_verif[i];
              b++;
          }
        }
        if(!b){(*nbre_coup)--;}
       }
char proposezUneLettre(){
      char caractere = getchar();
      caractere = toupper(caractere);
       while(getchar()!='\n');
       return caractere;
}
```

Comment: Good. You ought to edit your answer to make clear that this solved the problem, and explain a bit about what you changed. Comments can disappear, and future users who find this question through a search will have an easier time understanding the solution this way. And, welcome to Stack Overflow :)